# Web address PHP redirect

Tags: php, mysql, database, redirect

I am currently working on a social networking website, and I would like the user to be able to enter the web address of another user and be redirected to his profile. The thing is, every existing user has a column in a mySQL DataBase, which specifies what page templates does he use, and the data to be inputted into this template. How can i Possibly make it so that when he inputs of example : http://www.emuze.co/users/@bob_marly (it can have a .PHP/ .HTML suffix after it), the website will query the Database, find the template, redirect to that templates page (e.g. http://www.emuze.co/temps/temp1.0.php) and use the users that a from the mySQL Database?
I know its a very long and complicated question, but i would really appreciate any help!
thanks a lot! :@

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't just redirect to the target site? For real, I mean. Instead of handling redirection internally by showing something else than you should display, just forward the user to the target page. You can either use the HTTP Location header for that or a meta-tag. (If this doesn't make sense, maybe I didn't get your question at all.)

Comment: I'm not sure whether "working on a social networking website" means writing one, or using an existing one. If this is a server that you have control of, the answer is to use Ajax, talking to a back-end process that queries the database. If not, then you can't do it unless the facility is provided by the server.

Comment: no i am making my own one from scratch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give each user a row instead of a column, within a table that specifies which template is used for each user.

For example, you would have the "templates"-table, with the columns "UserID", "Username" and "Template". Then, the table would look something like this:

```
+--------+----------+----------+
| UserID | Username | Template |
+--------+----------+----------+
|      1 | John     | temp1.0  |
|      2 | Paul     | temp1.1  |
|      3 | Eric     | temp1.0  |
|      4 | Frank    | temp1.2  |
+--------+----------+----------+
```

...and soforth.

Then you'd have to query which template a user has. For example, to know which template the user with UserID '3' uses, assuming your mysql connection resource is stored in the variable $link:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM templates WHERE UserID=3";
$result = $link->query($query);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

$row['Template'] will result 'temp1.0' which you could use for including a specific CSS-stylesheet, including specific PHP-files or whatever, but you can also retrieve all other user-specific information such as $row['Username']. No need for redirections.

Comment: but what i wanted to do is just like what you just wrote, but I want to make it so that a random GUEST can go to the user's URL and then this will automatically query the database and find the user's information and template, though such a page doesn't actually exist (a page with the users name doesn't exist, there is only a script to turn the address into a variable and use it to query the database, then do some actions using the data from the database). Is that even possible? if not, how do you recommend doing it?

Comment: Maybe what you are searching for is .htaccess URL rewriting (mod_rewrite), in order to fetch a $_GET variable out of a 'static'-looking url? That way you can use www.emuze.co/temp.php?user=bob_marly as if it where www.emuze.co/users/@bob_marly, then querying using the $_GET['user'] variable  http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right, you mean this:

So user A wants to see the site from user B. 
User A has template T_A, user B has template T_B. 
User A goes to www.emuze.co/users/B and watches it using template T_A.

If this is right, do it like this:
Read out the data from user B from the database. Load the watchings user profile, check wich template he is using and then render the site using the template (in this cast T_A) and the data of the user (B).

Very easy example:

user database:

```
|Name  | Information       | Template
_______________________________________
|A     |I'm user A         | T_A
|B     |I'm user B         | T_B
```

Templates:
T_A:

```
   "Hey, I am %NAME%, Some Infos about me: %INFORMATION%"
```

T_B:

```
   "Name: $NAME", Information: %INFORMATION"
```

User A wants to look at User B:

```
Get user B's values from db
Get user A's Template
replace `%NAME%` and `%INFORMATION%`
print it
```

UPDATE:

I think what you need is some mod_rewrite (under Apache, under IIS use rewrite rules), wich maps http://example.com/users/bob_marley to http://example.com/users/index.php?user=bob_marley. Using this you always get to that site and can do anything there.

You should not use a real existing file per user, but one wich gets params like this. And you should use a template system, so you can echo a templete everywhere without redirecting users.

Comment: but what i wanted to do is just like what you just wrote, but I want to make it so that a random GUEST can go to the user's URL and then this will automatically query the database and find the user's information and template, though such a page doesn't actually exist (a page with the users name doesn't exist, there is only a script to turn the address into a variable and use it to query the database, then do some actions using the data from the database). Is that even possible? if not, how do you recommend doing it?